# Dealing with empty associations in extjs 4 models

Tags: extjs

I've posted the same question to the Sencha forum: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?259313-Dealing-with-nulls-in-nested-data&p=949429#post949429

I'm having trouble understanding how associations are supposed to work (in ExtJS 4.1.1a).
Consider the following model:

```
Ext.define('FM.model.Project', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    requires: ['FM.model.Company'],

    fields: [
        'id',
        'customer_id',
        'parent_id',
        'name',
        'code',
        'supervisor_id',
        'start_date',
        'end_date',
        'budgeted_hours',
        'budgeted_sales',
        'budgeted_working_cost',
        'budgeted_material_cost',
        'info'
    ],

    associations: [
        {type: 'belongsTo', model: 'FM.model.Company', associatedName: 'Customer'},
        {type: 'belongsTo', model: 'FM.model.Project', associatedName: 'Parent'},
    ]
});
```

Sometimes the "parent" or "customer" in the JSON data is null, in which case the association getter should return null as well. But instead, I get an exception:

> Con is not a constructor

from ModelManager.js in create(). This happens because the BelongsTo association is trying to create a new instance with the associatedName (which is either "Parent" or "Customer"). This make zero sense to me.

How should I be handling such missing associations? Constructing a dummy new instance is not a good solution because I need to be able to tell if the associated data exists or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're right, it should create a `getter` function that returns `null`.

Here's a work-around:

set the `instanceName` of the `belongsTo` relationship, and check if it exists before calling the `getter`:

```
...
{type: 'belongsTo', model: 'FM.model.Company', associatedName: 'Customer', instanceName:'customer'}
...

if(myProject.customer){
  console.log(myProject.getCustomer().get('name'));
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/4TSDu/55/